# mysql Simple Query + if

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Seems like I'm not able to do a simple query.

What I want to achieve is all the results that have 'best2' value '1' so the div will be attached to only those results.

Right now , the div 'badge-best2div' attaches to ALL the products.

I don't know what I'm missing out.

```
<?php $show = true; ?>
        <?php

        $roman  = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Product")
                                  ->where("status = 1")
                                  ->andWhere("site_id = ? ", SITE_ID)
                                  ->andWhere("best2 = 1")
                                  ->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

         ?>
        <?php if ($product->getIsTop()  && !isset($hide_badge_top)): $show = false;?>
            <div class="badge-top"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($roman['best2']){ 
            $show = false;      ?>
            <div class="badge-best2div"></div>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($product->getIsBestBuy() && !isset($hide_badge_bestbuy) && $show): ?>
            <div class="badge-bestbuy"></div>
        <?php endif ; ?>
```

Comment: best2 column is in where clause, `$roman['best2']` exist in all cases

Answer (score 0):

got it working using

```
<?php if (($roman['best2'])==1){
```